# SED not working on files copied using the COPY command in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, sed, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker so please be kind.

I have a `Dockerfile` I'm working on that uses the `COPY` instruction to copy some files into an image I'm building. The `COPY` is working fine, the files end up in my Docker image at the end. The problem I have is when using the `RUN` command to execute a `sed` find and replace statement on some of the files I just copied to the image does not appear to make the changes in the final `docker` image.

This is the build command I'm using.

```
docker build --build-arg web_domain=mydomain.com -t me/myproject:latest .
```

Here is a sample of the Dockerfile.

```
FROM mattrayner/lamp:latest-1804

# Custom Arguments
ARG web_domain

# Copy Files Into Image
COPY /app/src/ /app/src/


# Add Domain to config
RUN sed -i "s|\$domain = '';|\$domain = '${web_domain}';|g" /app/src/config.ini

# Entrypoint
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

I'm expecting that this file `/app/src/config.ini` will contain a line in it that looks like:

```
$domain = 'mydomain.com';
```

What I'm finding is the file in the resulting docker container when it is run looks like this.

```
$domain = '';
```

I'm suspecting that because the copied file is not part of the base image that my changes with the `sed` command are only applied to the container produced with the `RUN` instruction. If that's the case how do I get the edited file into the `docker` image I'm trying to build?

Comment: do you see any errors or massages?

Comment: your image works fine on my machine with the test examples you provided. Can you add how you start the image and how you check the content of the file?

Comment: @LinPy No I don't see any errors

Comment: @Stefano I run it like this.

docker run -it --name myproject -p "4433:443" -v "$(pwd)/updates:/updates" -v "$(pwd)/mysql:/var/lib/mysql" me/myproject:latest

Then once it's running I cat out the contents of the file like this


docker exec -it myproject cat /app/src/config.ini

Comment: I don&#39;t see any issue here. Maybe you can 'cat config.ini' during the build and see of the content is right at build time.

Comment: @Stefano I have already tried that, and when I do a cat within the same layer during a build I can see that the file has been changed. However when I run the resulting image file the updated config.ini file no longer has those changes. It's like the changes are not being saved to the image that I'm running.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your effort in checking this out. The sample Docker file was a subset of a larger Dockerfile but it did hold the essential commands that I needed to work. I've since resolved this issue by simply running the SED command much earlier in the build process, directly after I do the COPY command.

I also added the following setting to my Docker config but I don't think it's related.

"features": {"buildkit": true}